# Const-Correctness on complex return value

Tags: c++, const-correctness

struct Foo {
        char * DataPtr;
    };

```
class ISomeInterface {
public:
    Foo GetFoo( ) const;
    Foo GetFoo( );
};
```

The `Foo::DataPtr` is a pointer to an internal buffer of the object behing `ISomeInterface`. Is there a way to make sure that the `Foo::DataPtr` returned by the const version of `ISomeInterface::GetFoo` is a `const char *` ?

Comment: Foo::DataPtr is a type so is char const* - what do you mean - if you want toi return char const* then just declare as char const* GetFoo() cons;

Comment: Foo::DataPtr is not a type but a member of the struct Foo with the type char * (or const char *). In the real world, Foo is more complex, so returning a char * (or const char *) is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a

```
struct ConstFoo {
   const char* DataPtr;
};
```

for this. The const in C++ is not transitive. (this is also why you have `iterator` and `const_iterator`.)

Comment: So, no simple solution then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A struct

```
struct Foo {  
    char * DataPtr;  
}
```

is not the same as

```
struct Foo {  
    const char * DataPtr;
}
```

so you cannot differentiate how you would like.

You could make the const `GetFoo()` return a const `Foo` object (which I suspect is not what you want, as it will make all the member variables const), or make another struct with a `const char * DataPtr` (say `FooConst`) which is returned on the const call.

Comment: Actually, I could use a const object, since it is just a data object that is supposed to be read-only. I was just not sure if I can use const on an object, or just on references and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the design of your `Foo` and 'hide' the acess to `DataPtr` behind functions. For instance:

```
class Foo {
    char * DataPtr;
public:
    //just some examples
    void doThis() const {}
    void doThat() {}
}; 

class ISomeInterface {
public:
    const Foo GetFoo( ) const { return Foo(); }
    Foo GetFoo( ) { return Foo(); }
}; 

...

const Foo foo1 = ISomeInterface().GetFoo();
foo1.doThis();
foo1.doThat(); //error
Foo foo2 = ISomeInterface().GetFoo();
foo2.doThis();
foo2.doThat();
```

Providing functions that define which operations are const and those that are not you can avoid duplicating your `Foo` and obtain the const-correctness restrictions you seem to be aiming for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping to get it working without that, to avoid unecessary code clutter.